# R unable too connect to open file

Tags: r

Have been getting these 2 response from r:

```
1:> source("C:/Users/conormurphy/Desktop/Chapter\ 2/Conor_datapipeline.R")
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

In addition: Warning message:

```
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/conormurphy/Desktop/Chapter 2/Conor_datapipeline.R': No such file or directory
2:> # Create our SQLite database
> conn <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "C:/Users/conormurphy/Tweet_Data.db")
Error: Could not connect to database:
unable to open database file
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure these files exist? How are you running these commands (RStudio, Command line, etc.)?

Comment: The error is almost certainly due to a misspelling of the path, not an R-specific problem.